# Android data Binding - ObservableArrayMap how to implement in a POJO

Tags: android, data-binding

From the observable objects section of the android blog on [data binding](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#data_binding_layout_files)

The POJO class should extend BaseObservable unless your using ObservableFields.  Let's look at my current POJO which is very simple and just stores an observableInt:

```
public class User {
public ObservableInt visible;

public User(int visible) {
    this.visible=new ObservableInt(visible);
}
```

}

I want to add an Observable Collection to this pojo but im not clear how to layout the xml if i do that.  How would i call it.  Lets say i want to add the current arraymap to my POJO:

```
ObservableArrayMap<String, Object> myCollection = new ObservableArrayMap<>();
myCollection.put("firstName", "Google");
myCollection.put("lastName", "Inc.");
myCollection.put("age", 17);
```

How do i incorporate this into my xml for data binding. My xml file is simple and looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="com.example.android.floatingactionbuttonbasic.User"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="my first textview"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="my second textview"
            android:visibility="@{user.visible}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I am confused how i would add variables for ObservableArrayMap into this xml file and be able to use it.  Can someone help ?I feel i can pass it into the User POJO fine, its just from xml i dont know how i'd reference it? The reason im confused is because the ObservableArrayMap is going to be a attribute of the User class, how do i access it since its going to be a member of the User class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the map values like any other public observable from your xml.

For example:

```
public class Model{
    public ObservableArrayMap<Integer,String> MyMap=new ObservableArrayMap<>();
    public Model(){
        MyMap.put(1,"easy");
    }
}
```

Access the value from your xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="de.example.models.Model"/>

    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
        android:text="@{model.MyMap.get(1)}"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: You may also access it in a simpler expression syntax: "@{model.MyMap[1]}"

Comment: Note that refreshes occur on any and all changes to the map, not to specific keys. So all views with data binding expressions that reference an `ObservableMap` are refreshed when an element is added or removed from that map -- not just the views with data binding expressions that reference that individual map key.